# Issue with network post drive cloning

Tags: linux

I am cloning my 480GB to a 960GB and do so successfully using pmagic/clonezilla. Before cloning I have network connectivity and after cloning I don’t. When I go back to pmagic I do have connectivity.

- ip a shows same NICs
- dmesg shows same msgs regarding eth as before the clone so nothing new
- netplan wasn’t changed (Ubuntu 18)
- Did netplan configure and apply of course as well as rebooting

Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: I'd check all IP configurations including DNS, gateway, IP, etc. before and after for a starting point just in case. Does reconfiguring the IP settings fix the issue? Is it DHCP configured or do you have some hard-coded configurations for IP settings?

Comment: Thank you for replying, yeah netplan is identical and it is set to static with the exact settings as before